# Delphi - Multithread port checker

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I'm trying to convert a single thread application to a multi thread application.

Basically, I want to check simultaneously at every 10 seconds,50 ports at once and see if they are online or offline.

I'm using a listbox to load all the ip and ports (127.0.0.1:50008) they I parse the ip and port number and check it using this function:

```
uses idTCPclient;

function IsPortActive(AHost : string; APort : string): boolean;
var
  IdTCPClient : TIdTCPClient;
begin
  Result := False;
  try
    IdTCPClient := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
    try
      IdTCPClient.Host := AHost;
      IdTCPClient.Port := strtoint(APort);
      IdTCPClient.ConnectTimeout:=50;
      IdTCPClient.Connect;
      Result := True;
    finally
      IdTCPClient.Free;
    end;
  except
    //Ignore exceptions
  end;
end;
```

Here is the procedure to start checking the port and signal the result accordingly:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if isportactive('127.0.0.1','50008') then
    listbox_online.items.add(ip+''+port)
  else
    listbox_offline.items.add(ip+''+port);
end;
```

Could someone please guide me how to convert this as a thread that can accept IP and port as parameter?

Comment: Create a thread. Pass it the necessary information when created. Move the code into the thread's Execute method. That's it. Well, all UI needs to be invoked back on the UI thread but I guess you know that.

Comment: Could you please post an example?

Comment: No. There are countless examples on the web showing how to create and execute threads. Start with some basic research. Ask a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: So, every 10 seconds, you want to create 50 threads which each connect to a different port? I think you'll find your bottleneck is actually in fact the network. It doesn't matter if you have 1,000 threads, your network is still going to throttle them back. Better off with 1 thread checking them back to back.

Comment: Well I'm trying to find a way to monitor multiple ports at once. When the port is offline or closed I need to be able to see that right away.

Comment: What trouble are you having with the task?

Comment: I don't understand how to adapt the code above to the multithread concept.That's all.

Comment: You don't appear to have made any real effort. What have you read so far about threads?

Comment: Well I know that there are at least 4 ways to create a thread. However the examples that I run into were not simple enough to help me port the function above. I know that I cannot access any GUI related elements inside a thread because it's not thread safe. The main thread deals with the GUI elements so if I want to update GUI elements according to my calculations I have to use the Syncronize() method.

Comment: *I need to be able to see that right away* isn't going to happen. You're going to actually slow things down with all of the context switches that happen once you get more threads executing than you have cores. I don't think you've really thought this through, which means you clearly haven't done enough research before asking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to write the thread can be this one.

I have not added any extra `TNotifyEvent` methods because you can look for the properties you need in the thread's `OnTerminate` event.

```
type
  THostChecker = class(TThread)
    strict private
      FIdTCPClient: TIdTCPClient;
      FHost: string;
      FPort: Integer;
      FConnectTimeout: Integer;
      FIsPortActive: Boolean;
    protected
      procedure Execute; override;
    public
      constructor Create(const AHost: string; APort: Integer; AConnectTimeout: Integer = 50; CreateSuspended: Boolean = False);
      property IsPortActive: Boolean read FIsPortActive;
      property Host: string read FHost;
      property Port: Integer read FPort;
      destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

{ THostChecker}

constructor THostChecker.Create(const AHost: string; APort: Integer; AConnectTimeout: Integer; CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  FHost := AHost;
  FPort := APort;
  FConnectTimeout := AConnectTimeout;
  FIdTCPClient := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
  FIsPortActive := False;
end;

destructor THostChecker.Destroy;
begin
  FIdTCPClient.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure THostChecker.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  with FIdTCPClient do begin
    Host := FHost;
    Port := FPort;
    ConnectTimeout := FConnectTimeout;
    Connect;
    FIsPortActive := True;
  end;
end;
```

Here's the form relevant parts:

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  hosts: array [0..6] of string = ('google.com', 'stackoverflow.com', 'youtube.com', 'foo.org', 'null.org', 'porn.com', 'microsoft.com');
var
 i: Integer;
begin
  for i:=Low(hosts) to High(hosts) do
    with THostChecker.Create(hosts[i], 80, 50, False) do begin
      OnTerminate := HostCheckerTerminate;
      FreeOnTerminate := True;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm4.HostCheckerTerminate(Sender: TObject);
var
  hostChecker: THostChecker;
  ex: Exception;
  hostAndPort: string;
begin
  hostChecker := THostChecker(Sender);

  ex := Exception(hostChecker.FatalException);
  if Assigned(ex) then
    //do something useful here or don't evaluate ex at all

  hostAndPort := Format('%s:%d', [hostChecker.Host, hostChecker.Port]);

  if hostChecker.IsPortActive then
    listbox_online.items.add(hostAndPort)
  else
    listbox_offline.items.add(hostAndPort);
end;
```

The property `FreeOnTerminate` is set to `True` in order to avoid the call to `Free` for the thread itself.

The code which is executed in the `OnTerminate` event of a thread is already synchronized in the calling thread.

The threads do not raise exceptions in the calling tread but you can check if an exception has occurred in the `Execute` method evaluating the `FatalException` property in the `OnTerminate` event.

Comment: Thanks you very much for posting this example!

Comment: This may work for this particular scenario, however it should be noted that if, for example, you were using something other than `TIdTCPClient`, let's say a `TADOQuery`, you should not and can not create/free it in `Create` / `Destroy`. Instead, it should all be created within the context of the thread.

Comment: @user2858981 Thank you for [accepting it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if - for same strange reasons - the code above works for you! :D

Comment: @JerryDodge well... it was not intended to be an universal single-to-multi-thread converter

Comment: Thanks for this exemple.It works.I accept your solution. Unfortunately I also got downvoted for asking such "easy" question

Comment: @JerryDodge re-reading my comment to your last, it seems to me a little bit rude: I apologize since it wasn't my intention. Anyway... I don't get  the point with `TADOQuery` but I think the problem is the component owner. If it is so, isn't the component allowed to be created at runtime with a `nil` owner? If this applies, `TADOConnection` can be also created in the thread say as a `class var` or `threadvar`. Correct me if I'm wrong, I used to work with *ZeosLib* instead of *ADO* components, now with *kbMemTable*. Thank you.

Comment: ADO is COM, and COM can only be used within the thread which instantiated it. Create/Destroy are run in the context of the thread which spawned the new thread, not in the context of the new thread. This is the point I was trying to make, that everything needed by the thread should be managed from within the thread's `Execute` procedure. ADO being just an example of why the above approach would break.

Comment: @user2858981 you're welcome but please notice that there's a reason why your question was voted down actually. No matter if the argument is easy or not since *easy* is a relative concept because I might find it hard to do a job that you know perfectly. The point is that this site has some directives on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [mcve] and your question does not fit the model: you basically asked a *refactory* of your code so I can understand who downvoted.